# What delimiter could be used to parse string to list of regexps?

Tags: regex

I need to convert input string which is actual array of regexps separated by some delimiter.
Output - is list of strings where each string is regexp from input.

Question is what delimiter should I use to be sure that I will receive correct values.
Because it seems like regexp string could contain any set of characters, and in this case I need to decide what should be better for use as delimiter.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on the domain? Do you have any control over the format of the regular expressions?

Comment: How about an actual new line (and not the literal `\n`)?

Answer (score 3):

Building on @Theox's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21461275/2506021), a triple `+` is not valid in a regular expression and, assuming you expect the values to be valid regular expressions, could be used as a delimiter.

```
regex1+++regex2+++regex3
```

If a regular expression ended with a `+` or a double `+`, you'd have 4 or 5 `+` characters in a row. But, since a regular expression cannot start with a `+`, you'd know that the last three `+` characters represent the delimiter. For example,

```
a+++++b
```

would represent two regular expressions: `a++` and `b`.

Note that the double `+` is valid in a regular expression with the second `+` being the [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) so we cannot use only two `+` characters as the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You say its an Input-String and I assume you are able to manipulate it.
Why don't you use doubled character as delimiter? For example, I don't think you will use double semicolon in your regex, or triple.

```
regex1;;regex2;;regex3
```

Then

```
regexString.split(";;", regexString);
```

Comment: What if one of the regular expressions contains a double semicolon? I think it is not possible to do this without imposing a restriction on the regular expressions (e.g. must use `;{2}` instead of `;;` if you want to match double semicolons in the regular expression).

Comment: That is true and you already named the solution for this (;{2}). That is the strict way and the way I learned it. So sorry, I just did not think about it. In my opinion, it should always be used this way. But even though this should not be an issue if he is able to decide on regex format, I prefer your answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a double `+` as your delimiter.

It seems impossible to have a double `+` in a regexp, as it is a quantifier and it must be escaped to match the character.

So `regexp1++regexp2++regexp3` will work fine.

Edit : After seeing Rangi Keen's comment : two `+` is not enough, as it is still valid, but three `+` (or more) should do it !

`regexp1+++regexp2+++regexp3` will answer your problem.

Comment: The second `+` is the possessive quantifier of the first `+` (one or more). However, a triple `+` (`+++`) would not be a valid regular expression so could probably be used as a delimiter.

Comment: @RangiKeen Indeed, I tried on regexr, and it is possible to have two `+` in a row. Three `+` is invalid. What surprises me is that `+*` is invalid.

Comment: I was unaware of the possessive quantifiers myself until recently. It's not supported by javascript, but is available in java and other implementations. [Regex101](http://regex101.com/) is a good place to experiement with regular expressions and allows you to test against different implementations (the PCRE version is almost exactly the Java implementation).